# Point a domain to a URI of an IIS 7 website without changing the domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have setup a URL rewrite in IIS 7 for a particular site, that has 2 bindings.

1. main.mydomain.com
2. hub.mydomain.com

I have also applied a URL Rewrite Rule as shown below:

match `(.*)`
and then
under the condition
where `{HTTP_HOST}` matches `^hub\.mydomain\.com$`

301 redirect to

```
http://main.mydomain.com/hub/home.html
```

and this works, the purpose was to have `hub.mydomain.com` direct the user to a URI of `http://main.mydomain.com/hub/home.html`

I have now been asked to change this so that the `hub.mydomain.com` remains in the user's browser address but that they are shown the correct `/hub/home.html` content.

How can this be achieved? I presume that as the name suggests, URL Rewrite is no longer suitable? and if so how else can I do this?

**EDIT:**

`main.mydomain.com` still needs to go to the root of the website.

Comment: Couldn't you just set the default page to `/hub/home.html` for the website in IIS. Then, no matter if they browse to `http;//main.mydomain.com` or `http://hub.mydomain.com`, the browser will display the page located at the relative path `/hub/home.html` since both domains are mapped to that site in IIS.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that I still want `main.mydomain.com` to go to the home page of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, you state that `main.mydomain.com` and `hub.mydomain.com` are binded to a single website.

So if you want the users who hit `hub.mydomain.com` to be shown with the content from `http://main.mydomain.com/hub/home.html`, it is equivalent to have them hit `hub.mydomain.com` and be shwon the content from `http://hub.mydomain.com/hub/home.html`.

You rule would then go as:

```
<rule name="hub rewrite">
    <match url="^/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^hub\.mydomain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="hub/home.html" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, facepalm moment. The key here being the use of a rewrite and not a redirect and the relative path. Nice one. Out of interest, I used the IIS7 Url Rewrite feature on the site menu. Where is this <rule> xml applied?

Comment: It is applied in the `web.config`, inside the `<configuration><system.webServer></system.webServer></configuration>` section. Glad it helped!