# URL Rewrite for Web Portals on IIS 7.5 Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect / rewrite some url to my internal web server. I have setup the web server in the following way. Each portal is an ASP.NET application

- Web Server

  - Default Web Site

    - blog
    - forum
    - demo

The public links for these web portals are 
http://blog.example.com and 
http://forum.example.com

DNS is setup to forward all these urls to the web server.

I have tried some rule rewriting (at the Default Web Site level) and it is not working

```
<rules>
<rule name="blog" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^blog.example.com$" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/blog/" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="\blog\{R:0}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="forum" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^forum.example.com$" />
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/forum/" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="\forum\{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

Any suggestions / help in putting me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can this answer help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16903837/1443490 ?

Comment: @cheesemacfly : that link didn't work for me. thanks.

Comment: What is not working exactly?